# ArrayList elements refuse to be removed

Tags: java, arraylist

So, I'm making a random Hiragana name generator (don't ask why, okay?) and I've ran into a bit of a problem. The random name generator works fine for the most part but sometimes it generates long strings of repeated consonants for some reason. So instead of trying to address the problem directly like any normal programmer would, I've decided to try and scan through the ArrayList and delete repeated characters after the random generation:

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Iterator <String> it   = name.iterator();  
...      // insert random generation here                   
for (h = 0; h < s; h++) { // s is the length of the ArrayList
  ...    
  String curInd = name.get(h);
  String nextInd = name.get(h+1);
  if (curInd.equals(nextInd)) { // NOT 
    name.remove(h);             // WORKING
    s--;                        // :(
  }
}

String previousName = "";
while (it.hasNext()) {
String currentName = it.next();
if (currentName.equals(previousName)) {
    it.remove();
}
previousName = currentName;
}
```

This does not work. I'm not getting an error or anything, it just won't delete the repeated characters (or rather repeated Strings, since I made each character a String.) What could be the problem?

Comment: You are essentially changing the indexes as soon as you remove one element

Comment: Technically, you should be getting an error when you do name.get(h+1) because that will be an error when it runs off the end of the list. So, if you are not getting an error, then something strange is happening indeed. Fix that first!

Comment: Like I said, I added a check to see whether it was at the last element. `if (h != s-1) { //do stuff`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are changing the indexes as soon as you remove an item. Try using the `Iterator.remove()` function like the following:

```
Iterator<String> it = name.iterator();
String previousName = "";

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String currentName = it.next();
    if (currentName.equals(previousName)) {
        it.remove();
    }
    previousName = currentName;
}
```

Alternatively you can remove **all** the duplicates with the following one-liner:

```
names = new ArrayList<String>(new LinkedHashSet<String>(names));
```

Or even better, use `LinkedHashSet` or `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList` from the very start if you don't want any duplicates.

Comment: The Iterator approach is probably my best bet and I tried it out, but I got an exception thrown at me: "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException".

Comment: Did you use the `it.remove()` function? And did you make sure you called `it.next()` first?

Comment: Maybe add the new code you tried to your original question as an edit

Comment: I pretty much copied what you wrote verbatim. I edited the question to include the revision.

Comment: Did you remove/comment out your original for-loop?

Comment: Nope. But I don't understand how the iterations are concurring if one happens after the for loop is finished.

Comment: Also I need the other for-loop because it checks for other stuff.

Comment: NEVERMIND, I figured it out. It's because I declared the Iterator object before the for-loop instead of after it. It works perfectly now ! Thank you, based Samuel.

Comment: Try building the Iterator **after** your for-loop. I think it is complaining because you call name.remove() between the Iterator creation and the it.next()

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Iterator.remove` in order to remove the elements while traversing the list.

Answer (score 0):

Index needs to be less than `length` of `List`.

```
 String nextInd = name.get(h+1);
```

Above statement will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Yeah I know, I added a check to see whether it was at the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Use HashSet, it automatically removes repeated elements, but sorts elements in alphabetical order.

For Arraylist, Try to use this. This may help.

```
              int size=headlines.size();
     for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            // start from the next item after strings[i]
            // since the ones before are checked
            for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
                // no need for if ( i == j ) here
                if (!headlines.get(j).equals(headlines.get(i)))
                    continue;

                headlines.remove(j);
                // decrease j because the array got re-indexed
                j--;
                // decrease the size of the array
                size--;
            } // for j
        } // for i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a `Set` of some kind to automatically remove duplicate elements, for example...

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
name.add("A");
name.add("A");
name.add("B");
name.add("B");
name.add("B");
name.add("C");
name.add("C");
name.add("C");
System.out.println(name);
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
set.addAll(name);
System.out.println(set);
```

This will, of course, remove ALL duplicates, not just those that appear next to each other...

For example...

```
[A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C]
[A, B, C]
```

Or...

```
[A, B, C, B, C, B, C, A]
[A, B, C]
```

So it might not meet your immediate needs...

Comment: From the description I'd say the OP doesn't want any duplicates, you're right.